# how can i test the accelerometer sensors in my desktop PC with simulator of windows8 store app

Tags: app-store, windows-store-apps

i download the [Windows 8 app samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-Modern-Style-App-Samples) from Microsoft and one of these samples **accelerometer sensor sample**

[image: simulator visual studio 2012]

i dont know how can i test it for planning my software for using this feature ?

i haven't surface device and want to know is there only one way for do that? why we cant test it and shake it by mouse? why sensors not work in simulator when i rotate it ? why in simulator doesn't exist any button for shake simulator with mouse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the simulator doesn't emulate the accelerometer or other sensors other than location. You will need physical sensor hardware to test this.

[From MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/90f618c0-ce0e-4082-a2b9-5de257555461)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use the one from the Windows Phone Emulator

https://www.nuget.org/packages/XamlActions.AccelerometerSimulator/

ps: super-master-workaround. Use it at your own risk :)